# BI publisher sorting ASCII characters (lower case and ignore uppercase in sort)

Tags: oracle, sorting, obiee

I am trying to sort descr fields in BIP rtf template, and this is how I was able to sort it using the command `<?sort:DESCR;'ascending';data-type='text'?>`:

DESCR:

- AVPFinance
- Academic Advising
- Accounts Payable
- Alumni Services
- Anthropology
- Architectural

I want my sorting to push AVP finance to the end in the following order:

- Academic Advising
- Accounts Payable
- Alumni Services
- Anthropology
- Architectural
- AVPFinance

Is there a way to do it BI Publisher? as I can't edit the query or the xml to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BI Publisher sorts uppercase prior to lowercase.  So "Z" would before "a".

You can convert it to uppercase first, that will remove the problem.

This will sort by `DESCR` after converting everything to uppercase:

```
<?sort:(xdoxslt:convert_case(DESCR,'UPPER'));'ascending';data-type='text'?>
```

You may have to go into the Advanced properties to do something more advanced like this.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. thank you!

Comment: Glad it solved the problem! Please mark this as answered when you get a chance.